# filtering adsense from maps coordinates

Tags: google-maps, adsense

Is there a way for generating ads from a map view? Imagine I have a map view, and I want only ads relevant to that view to appear.

Or a least, can I filter the ads in my page using a place?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of you:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdWords/thread?tid=1bb8c4d7dce1a945&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for helping.What I want is to show them filtered in my page, not to create them. If I have a map view I want to filter the banner ads from map coordinates.